# How to get current Lat/Lng on Mobile Device via Webpage?

Tags: google-maps, mobile, google-maps-api-3, geolocation

I need to locate the current mobile location on the **Map via Webpage** (not via Mobile Native App). So as far as i understand, i need to know current "Lat/Lng" for my mobile device. How can i detect it?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this page could help you: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2010/03/08/entering-the-wonderful-world-of-geo-location/

Comment: Ghigo, hanks for the link. But when i follow the link http://isithackday.com/hacks/geo/distance.php .. my phone can show only "IP" location. Can't show "Geo Location". So is it possible for Mobiles or only my phone matters ? (My current mobile is Nokia S60v5)

Comment: It sounds like the browser on your phone doesn't support detecting your current location via a webpage.

Comment: Higher browser will supports it? So you mean, the "GeoLocation" functionality is depend on Browser Capability and NOT on the phone's native o/s or any other capability, right?

Comment: All the modern browser support it